# Coupled Resonators with sinusoidal coupling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, coupling

I have two coupled resonators with complex resonance frequencies of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. The coupling between them is varying sinusoidal with time. The time-evolution of their resonant mode field ($A,B$) can be written as:

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \iota\beta_1 A + \iota [\gamma\sin(\Omega t)]) B$$

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = \iota\beta_2 B + \iota [\gamma\sin(\Omega t) ] A$$

I want to get a comprehensive solution of this differential equation. I tried to look for books where periodic differential equations are explained but no success so far. Any idea how to find an exact solution of the differential equations above? $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\Omega$, and $\gamma$s are constants.

Comment: Is it $\gamma_2$ in the two equations ? Not $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ ? Is $\iota$ a plain constant ? Can we assume it to be $1$ ? Do the square brackets have a meaning of their own or are mere (unuseful) parentheses ?

Comment: Hi @JeanMarie the $\gamma_2$ is same in both equations (accidentally put the 2 subscript. Should have written it just gamma.) The $\iota$ is iota i.e. square root of -1. The square bracket are just parentheses. Please let me know if you need more info. Maybe I will just edit the $\gamma$s now.

Comment: Hi @JJacquelin I removed the tag. Can you please de-downvote the question now?

Answer (score 0):

Write your system under its matrix form :

$$\pmatrix{\frac{dA}{dt} \\ \frac{dB}{dt} }= \iota \underbrace{\pmatrix{\beta_1 & \gamma\sin(\Omega t)\\\gamma\sin(\Omega t) & \beta_2}}_M\pmatrix{A\\B}$$

whose solution (extension of the classical scalar ODE : $y'(t)=my(t) \implies y(t)=\exp(mt).y(0) $) is

$$\pmatrix{A\\B}=\exp(\iota M)\pmatrix{A_0\\B_0}$$

where $A(0),B(0)$ are the initial values.

If you work with Matlab, matrix exponentiation is done by "expm" function.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form solution ? There is one if $\beta_1=\beta_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am looking for close form solution. I can get to a close form if the $\beta$ are equal by adding and subtracting the equations and then using integration factor to solve them. However, I am not sure how to get an exact solution if $\beta$ are different. Google search shows I can use "Floquet Theory" but I don't have any idea about it at all.

Comment: Yes in the case $\beta_1=\beta_2$, it can be expressed using $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ functions. I have heard about Floquet theory. One thing you can do is to take the beginning of the series of the matrix exponential to get an "exact approximate solution" (!!!). Another thing is to attempt to work on the eigenvalues of matrix $M$...

Comment: This is wrong. The solution formula with the integral of $M$ in the exponent is only valid if all instances of $M$ commute. This is only the case if $\beta_1=\beta_2$. Otherwise one only gets the most general properties of Floquet theory.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann Any tips on how to solve it using Floquet Theory? Even if you can point me to a relevant literature, that would already be very helpful.

Comment: 1) Are you aware that, most of the time, closed-form solutions to differential equations do not exist ? 2) Did you know beforehand the expression with matrix exponentials ?